# Iphone Web apllication to recieve an XML from an API and display it contents

Tags: objective-c

I am developing an web application where i need to 
1)hit an url with username and password
2)get authenticated
3)pass parameters to another url(API)_ 
4)which will return me an xml
5)I have to parse that and display its contents in ma web app.

Kindly help me with small sample code and details.
Advance in thanks ,
Gans.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't how Stack Overflow works. You need try and write this code **yourself**. If you get stuck or can't resolve an issue you're having ask a targetted, specific question.

Additionally, there's a lot of sample code within Apple's Xcode documentation facility (nearly all of the various class reference docs have code samples attached) so it would be trival for you to find out such information yourself.

As a starter for ten, I'd recommend looking at:

1. [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
2. [Tree-Based XML Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/Articles/TraversingTree.html) (See the "Traversing an XML Tree" section.)

Comment: Thank you so much..!! I will start coding today !! If i get face any trouble i ll ask and clear my doubts !! thanks for providing the links and also timely reply..

Comment: @ganesh - No problems - hope it goes well. Incidentally, if you mark my answer as accepted, we'll both receive reputation points. (These are effectively the "currency" that keeps Stack Overflow rolling.) :-)